# Response of retrofit are not successful and desn't trigger the onFailure method

Tags: android, retrofit

I want to know in witch case the response will be diferent of .isSuccessful and not call onFailure method.

Comment: You'll need to provide more details for meaningful answers. What are you trying to do? What have you tried?

Comment: It probably means you aren't `enqueue()` -ing the callback or you are not waiting for the async response.

Answer (score 1):

isSuccessful() method returns status in case call has been performed

```
public boolean isSuccessful() {
    return this.code >= 200 && this.code < 300;
}
```

onFailure will be called when you get exception and your call won't be even executed till the end